# Best way to document a Vue JS and Quasar application

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I tried to implement the documentation with the JSDoc for VueJS plugin without success

https://github.com/Kocal/jsdoc-vuejs

What is the best tool available to document an application made with Vue and Quasar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. **JSDoc with Plugins**:

   - The plugin you mentioned ([jsdoc-vuejs](https://github.com/Kocal/jsdoc-vuejs)) is an option to make JSDoc work with Vue files.
   - If you encounter issues with this or any other plugin, I'd recommend first checking for updates, reading through open/closed GitHub issues, and trying out configurations others have shared.
   - Sometimes, it's also worth revisiting the plugin's documentation, as a slight oversight can lead to problems.
2. **Vuese**:

   - [Vuese](https://vuese.org/) is a tool specifically designed to document Vue components. It parses your Vue components and generates documentation based on them.
   - It's an excellent choice if you want a tool that is designed with Vue in mind. However, I'm not sure about its compatibility or special integrations with Quasar.
3. **Vue Styleguidist**:

   - [Vue Styleguidist](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/) is a Vue-specific style guide generator and component explorer.
   - It's more focused on showcasing and documenting components interactively than on purely static documentation.
4. **Storybook for Vue**:

   - While [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/get-started/introduction) is not a documentation tool in the traditional sense, it provides an interactive UI to view and test your Vue components in various states.
   - You can also integrate [Storybook Docs](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/next/addons/docs) to automatically generate documentation based on your stories.
5. **Custom Documentation**:

   - Sometimes, the best approach, especially for larger applications or libraries, is a combination of generated documentation (from one of the tools mentioned above) and custom-written docs.
   - Tools like [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) or [Nuxt Content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) can help you build beautiful documentation sites that integrate well with Vue.